# Overfitting, underfitting or good fit?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So im training an lstm rnn for a binary text classification task and i am having some issues understanding the loss results. The training set is roughly 700 000 examples, and the validation set is around 35000 examples. 
**The validation set and training set are independent, so i am not training on the data in the validation set.**
From what ive learnt in school and while checking some other posts, the validation loss should be slightly higher than the training loss to be a good fit. In my case however as you can see the validation loss fluctuates quite abit. I am using binary cross entropy for the loss function.

I am running the validation set at every 300 batches of training data since i put the batch size at 128. So every 300 batches of training data means the algorithm has mowed through roughly the size of the validation set so every 300 batches felt like a good measuring point.

I dont quite understand how to interpret these results though. The accuracy is fine, around 79% on validation set after 3 epochs and 78-82% on training set. But i am not sure if i have overfitted/underfitted.

Dont mind the x axis labels, they formatted weirdly. This picture is after around 3 full epochs, just starting the 4th.
[image]
´

Comment: Does the training set contains the validation set, or they are independent?

Comment: They are independent

Answer (score 0):

If training and validation are independent, **it seems that you do not overfit**: your training and validation errors are very close. If your validation loss begins to increase while your training continues to decrease, you are benning to overfit, but that is not the case here.

Whether you underfit or not is more difficult to tell and depends higly on the problem and your data.

The fact that validation loss fluctuates is absolutely normal. Especially as it is a bit small compared to your training set.

In order to get more knowledge about your model, you could compute other metrics such as F1 socre, ROC, precision-recall curve, etc.

Another interesting thing to do would be to look at some pairs of input and predicted output to get a more precise idea of what is going on: for the false positive and false negative in particular.

One very important step is to try to "explain" your model behaviour using sensitivity analysis techniques such Sobol indices (ANOVA) or [SHAP values](https://github.com/slundberg/shap).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i will try some of the things suggested. When would you suggest i stop training, given that the validation loss fluctuates i cant just stop training if it increases once. Should i wait until it continously increases over several batches?

Comment: On classical "early stopping" strategy consists in stopping the training when no minimum validation loss has been reached for `p` steps (`p` being an integer hyperparameter). Note that you should not use the same dataset for early stopping and for the final validation, in order to avoid overfitting and adding bias